# Correct way to declare properties

Tags: ios, properties

I am little confused about specifying strong, copy, or assign and not specifying them. We don't use NIB files. My colleague always use following - he says iOS detects it and use it automatically strong, weak etc.

```
@interface viewController : UIViewController
   @property (nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView1;
   @property (nonatomic) NSUInteger num;
   @property (nonatomic) NSArray *array;
@end
```

I prefer following way doing it.

```
@interface viewController : UIViewController
   @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView1;
   @property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger num;
   @property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *array;
@end
```

Which one is better programming style? First option always have strong type as it defaults but I always specifies them explicitly.

Comment: For any property: atomic, readwrite and strong - are the default values. Hence both your options works as same. But it is always better if coder tells to compiler what to assign as property.

Comment: I should have mentioned it that I know strong is default so technically both are same but I mean for other types as well. Edited question.

Comment: For those, as i said - it is always better if developer/coder tells compiler explicitly and declare those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in earlier answers, in Objective C properties are by default,

- `atomic, strong/retain, readwrite`  --> For pointer types
- `atomic, assign, readwrite`         --> For primitive types

Property types `weak`, `copy` need to be explicitly specified by the programmer and in **no way** gets automatically decided.

What does each mean,

- `strong`/`retain` referenced objects are kept alive in the memory until specified.
- `weak` referenced objects will be destroyed when there is no strong reference. Typically used to reference `delegate` objects.
- `copy` will create a shallow copy of the object getting assigned to the property.
- `assign`/`usafe_unretained`(ARC) assigns the value. If used in case of pointer types this is an unsafe unretained assignment of the pointer. In ARC, typically use `weak` for pointer types because it will make the `ivar=nil` once `weak` referenced object is destroyed. `assign` in this case will lead to dangling pointer.

Personally, I prefer specifying property types even if it `strong` by default. This adds readability, which comes handy specially when profiling application for memory leaks or debugging crashes.

You can read more about [properties here](http://rdcworld-iphone.blogspot.in/2012/12/variable-property-attributes-or.html).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

With ARC, strong is the default so the two are technically the same. From the [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html):

```
__strong is the default. An object remains “alive” as long as there is a strong pointer to it.
```

Note that ARC will *NOT* automatically detect when something needs to be weak, however.

I tend to be explicit, like your second example, but I think it's mostly a matter of style/habit.

Answer (score 0):

The default for a **property** is `strong`and for a **variable** is `__strong` too. In your current example the *recommended* property would actually be `weak`, but `strong` is acceptable too.

For properties of non-primitives you should no longer use `assign`, but rather `unsafe_unretained`. Practically they're the same, but the latter lets you know that you're using an object unsafely.

The `copy` property means that an object is copied (using the `copy` method) and not retained. It's recommended for classes such as `NSString` and `NSArray`, which have mutable forms. This is because you don't want to retain what you think is an immutable string but is actually being changed elsewhere.

The `assign` property declaration should be used only for primitive types and structs, e.g. `int` and `CGSize`.

Comment: Your current example has changed, so I'll clarify that I meant in regards to declaring a UIImageView.